# quantlib build failing on Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan with linker error

Tags: c++, macos, linker, x86-64, quantlib

I got the following error:

> Error Details:
>     "non-virtual thunk to QuantLib::ExtendedBlackVarianceSurface::update()", referenced from:
>         vtable for QuantLib::ExtendedBlackVarianceSurface in testQuantlib.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [testQuantlib] Error 1

Comment: Too little information. What are you trying to build, QuantLib itself or some program using it? What was the command line?

Comment: Hi, I am beginner to quantLib and trying to set up the environment using Eclipse on Mac OSX. I have installed the binaries for quantLib and required Boost Library. Boost seems working fine but I am getting error while running simple quantlib examples. I had made initial search, and it seems to be issue with gcc standard stdlibc++ and linker lstdc++. Tried setting that too but got unrecognised flag from g++

Comment: Are you linking QuantLib to your program?

Comment: Yes, I linking QuantLib.

Comment: Ok, I think it's better if you take this to the QuantLib mailing list. You'll have a better chance at some useful feedback.